# Display each looped item in different divs

Tags: javascript, html

### Display each item in different divs

I wrote this code to loop through an object, they all currently display in the same div but i want each item to display in its own div. 
How can i make that possible?

```
<textarea id="text">
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "python",
          "display_name": "Python",
          "short_description": "Python is a dynamically typed programming language.",
          "description": "Python is a dynamically typed programming language designed by Guido Van Rossum. Much like the programming language Ruby, Python was designed to be easily read by programmers. Because of its large following and many libraries, Python can be implemented and used to do anything from webpages to scientific research.",
          "created_by": "Guido van Rossum",
          "released": "February 20, 1991",
          "created_at": "2016-12-07T00:07:02Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-27T22:45:43Z",
          "featured": true,
          "curated": true,
          "score": 111.92691
        },
        {
          "name": "jekyll",
          "display_name": "Jekyll",
          "short_description": "Jekyll is a simple, blog-aware static site generator.",
          "description": "Jekyll is a blog-aware, site generator written in Ruby. It takes raw text files, runs it through a renderer and produces a publishable static website.",
          "created_by": "Tom Preston-Werner",
          "released": "2008",
          "created_at": "2016-12-16T21:53:08Z",
          "updated_at": "2017-10-27T19:00:24Z",
          "featured": true,
          "curated": true,
          "score": 45.06729
        },
        {
          "name": "sass",
          "display_name": "Sass",
          "short_description": "Sass is a stable extension to classic CSS.",
          "description": "Sass is a stylesheet language with a main implementation in Ruby. It is an extension of CSS that makes improvements to the old stylesheet format, such as being able to declare variables and using a cleaner nesting syntax.",
          "created_by": "Hampton Catlin, Natalie Weizenbaum, Chris Eppstein",
          "released": "November 28, 2006",
          "created_at": "2016-12-16T21:53:45Z",
          "updated_at": "2018-01-16T16:30:40Z",
          "featured": true,
          "curated": true,
          "score": 42.455986
        },
        {
          "name": "homebrew",
          "display_name": "Homebrew",
          "short_description": "Homebrew is a package manager for macOS.",
          "description": "Homebrew is a package manager for Apple's macOS operating system. It simplifies the installation of software and is popular in the Ruby on Rails community.",
          "created_by": "Max Howell",
          "released": "2009",
          "created_at": "2016-12-17T20:30:44Z",
          "updated_at": "2018-02-06T16:14:56Z",
          "featured": true,
          "curated": true,
          "score": 19.194168
        }
      ]
    }   
    </textarea>


    <div id="display" style="border: 3px solid green"></div>


        var gitHubData = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

        var newGitHubData = JSON.parse(gitHubData);

    function functn(){

      for(var i = 0; i < newGitHubData.items.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += 
        ("Items-" + "<br> " 
          + "Name: "  + newGitHubData.items[i].name + ", <br> " 

          + "Display Name: " + newGitHubData.items[i].display_name + ", <br "

          + "Created By: " + newGitHubData.items[i].created_by + ", <br " 

          + "Released: " + newGitHubData.items[i].released + ", <br> " 

          + "Created At: " + newGitHubData.items[i].created_at + ", <br> " 

          + "Updated At: " + newGitHubData.items[i].updated_at + ", <br> " 

          + "Featured: " + newGitHubData.items[i].featured + ", <br> " 

          + "Curated: " + newGitHubData.items[i].curated + " , <br> " 

          + "Score: " + newGitHubData.items[i].score  + "<br> " 
          );
      }

    }
    functn();
```

Each looped item should display in its own div
 [This is what displays currently, but each item should be in different div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dFkB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am new here too but let me try to answer this. First I see that you are displaying everything in the loop to a single div with the id="display". So everything would be in just that single div and not separately. To have them in separate divs you can have the display div as a root div without the green border and enclose the content displayed by the loop in a div that has the green border. This way each loop will be in it's own div.

```
<div id="display"></div>

    var gitHubData = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;

    var newGitHubData = JSON.parse(gitHubData);

function functn(){

  for(var i = 0; i < newGitHubData.items.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += 
    ("<div id='displayinn' style='border: 3px solid green'> Items-" + "<br> " 
      + "Name: "  + newGitHubData.items[i].name + ", <br> " 

      + "Display Name: " + newGitHubData.items[i].display_name + ", <br "

      + "Created By: " + newGitHubData.items[i].created_by + ", <br " 

      + "Released: " + newGitHubData.items[i].released + ", <br> " 

      + "Created At: " + newGitHubData.items[i].created_at + ", <br> " 

      + "Updated At: " + newGitHubData.items[i].updated_at + ", <br> " 

      + "Featured: " + newGitHubData.items[i].featured + ", <br> " 

      + "Curated: " + newGitHubData.items[i].curated + " , <br> " 

      + "Score: " + newGitHubData.items[i].score  + "<br> </div>" 
      );
  }

}
functn();
```

I hope this will help you to achieve what you want to.

Comment: Yh, i got the desired result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('text').value);
const container = document.getElementById('display');
items.forEach(item => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `
   Items-
   Name: ${item.name}
    Display Name: ${item.display_name}
    Created By: ${item.created_by}
    Released: ${item.released}
    Created At: ${item.created_at}
    Updated At: ${item.updated_at}
    Featured: ${item.featured}
    Curated: ${item.curated}
    Score: ${item.score}
  `;
  div.classList.add('item');
  container.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```